# I want to click on an element to toggle a class being referenced on a completely unrelated element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to click on an element to toggle a class being referenced on a completely unrelated element (not a child, parent or sibling): 
For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">
    this is button!!!
  </button>
  <div class="allo">
    test
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">
    this is button!!!
  </button>
  <div class="allo">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.allo {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript: *(or something like this)*

```
var el = document.getElementByClassName("allo");

  function toggle(){
    for (i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {
      if (el[i].style.display === 'none'){
        el[i].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        el[i].style.display = 'none'
      }
    }
  }
```

When clicking on the button in the parent's div, open a block of text belonging to this parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/5sw4btga/

Comment: not Element, but Elements

Comment: thanks it's a typo
 :)

Comment: Are you wanting to toggle the class on all `allo` by any `btn` click?

Comment: u can find a solution under my post :) Thanks for help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's use `document.querySelectorAll` for this and update your script with some more modern JS.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn"); //we can select them on the same manner as css selectors.
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".allo");

//borrow array's forEach to iterate over the node list
//use call to pass the node list (btn) as this
Array.prototype.forEach.call(btn, function(element, index){
  //use bind to pass index to the function

  element.addEventListener("click", toggleViewFunc.bind(element, index), false);
  //use addEventListener to attach click handlers
});

function toggleViewFunc(index)
{
  //because the button is in the same parent as the div "allo" the indices match. 
  //if this is not the case you could use this.nextSibling instead of el[index] because "allo" is the sibling of button.
  //use classlist and toggle to turn show or off.
  el[index].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.allo {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
}

/*introduce extra show class */
.show{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">
    this is button!!!
  </button>
  <div class="allo">
    test
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">
    this is button!!!
  </button>
  <div class="allo">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **THANK U VERY VERY MUCH!** I spent a lot of hours with this problem!! U made my day!! uwwee:) I'm happy! :)

Answer (score 0):

- **Issue 1**: You did not declare `i` before using it in your for loop.
- **Issue 2**: you have a typo, it's [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), not `getElementByClassName`

You will need an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for you buttons. I updated your Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6oz0tsgp/

```
/* change "Element" to "Elements" */
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("allo");
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
/* declare i */
var i = 0;

/** 
 *  call Array.prototype because the HTMLCollection 
 *  returned by getElementsByClassName does not have 
 *  a forEach-Property 
 */
Array.prototype.forEach.call(btn, function (current) {
   current.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
})

function toggle(){
    for (i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].style.display === 'none') {
            el[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            el[i].style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT !! Be happy!! ) and **for better karma !! ++++**

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you are looking for? The button passes itself to the toggle function, then we go one up in the HTML, we look through all the HTML elements of this element searching for the element with the 'allo' class , and after we find this element we alter its display. The other element stays unharmed.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(btn, function (current) {
   current.addEventListener('click', toggle(current), false);
})

function toggle(el){
    var divParent = el.parentElement;
    var divsInsideParent = divParent.children;
    var divAllo = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < divsInsideParent.length; i = i + 1){
        if (divsInsideParent[i].classList.contains("allo")){
            divAllo = divsInsideParent[i];
        }
    }
    if (divAllo.style.display === 'none') {
        divAllo.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        divAllo.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For your solution! !)